# Can't load facebook profile image

Tags: objective-c, facebook, sdk, ios9

I have a problem with uploading profile picture from facebook to my API and saving  to Parse. This code is from Udemy.  I'm using Xcode 7.2.

Error:

```
2016-01-18 10:14:15.296 MatchedUp[14381:5418567] Error in FB request Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<PFReceptionist: 0x12663d2e0>, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
   body =     {
       error =         {
           code = 100;
           "fbtrace_id" = "FXTRrxOh0+c";
           message = "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (photo) on node type (User)";
           type = OAuthException;
       };
   };
   code = 400;
}}
```

Code:

```
-(void)updateUserInformation
{
//
        FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/?fields=name,birthday,first_name,location,gender,interested_in,photo"];
        [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

        if(!error){
            NSDictionary *userDictionary = (NSDictionary *)result;

            //create URL
            NSString *facebookID = userDictionary[@"id"];
            NSLog(@"%@",result);
            NSURL *pictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1", facebookID]];
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:pictureURL];
           // UIImage *fbImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            NSLog(@"%@",result);
            NSMutableDictionary *userProfile = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:8];
          NSLog(@"%@",result);
            if(userDictionary[@"name"]){
                userProfile[kCCUserProfileNameKey] = userDictionary[@"name"];
            }
            if(userDictionary[@"user_birthday"]){
                userProfile[kCCUserProfileBirthdayKey] = userDictionary[@"user_birthday"];
            }
            if(userDictionary[@"first_name"]){
                userProfile[kCCUserProfileFirstNameKey] = userDictionary[@"first_name"];
            }
            if(userDictionary[@"location"][@"name"]){
                userProfile[kCCUserProfileLocationNameKey] = userDictionary[@"location"][@"name"];
            }
            if(userDictionary[@"gender"]){
                userProfile[kCCUserProfileGenderKey] = userDictionary[@"gender"];
            }
            if(userDictionary[@"interested_in"]){
                userProfile[kCCUserProfileInterestedInKey] = userDictionary[@"interested_in"];
            }

            if([pictureURL absoluteString]){
                userProfile[kCCUserProfilePictureURL] = [pictureURL absoluteString];
            }

            [[PFUser currentUser] setObject: userProfile forKey:kCCUserProfileKey];
            [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
            [self requestImage];

        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Error in FB request %@", error);
        }
    }];
}

-(void) uploadPFFileToParse:(UIImage *)image
{
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8);

    if(!imageData){
        NSLog(@"imageData was not found");
        return;
    }


    PFFile *photoFile = [PFFile fileWithData:imageData];

    [photoFile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if(succeeded){
            PFObject *photo = [PFObject objectWithClassName:kCCPhotoClassKey];
            [photo setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:kCCPhotoUserKey];
            [photo setObject:photoFile forKey:kCCPhotoPictureKey];
            [photo saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                NSLog(@"Photo saved successfully");
            }];
        }
    }];
}

-(void) requestImage
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kCCPhotoClassKey];
    [query whereKey:kCCPhotoUserKey equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

    [query countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if(number == 0 )
        {
            PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
            self.imageData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

            NSURL *profilePictureUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:user [kCCUserProfileKey][kCCUserProfilePictureURL]];
            NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:profilePictureUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:4.0f];
            NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
            if(!urlConnection){
                NSLog(@"Failed to Download Picture");
            }
        }
    }];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.imageData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    UIImage *profileImage = [UIImage imageWithData:self.imageData];
    [self uploadPFFileToParse:profileImage];
}
@end
```

Any idea how can i fix this problem?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Field name for the profile picture is `picture`, not `photo`.

Comment: @CBroe I changed, but still doesn't work.  Now don't display error message but I can't see uploading file in Parse. Do you know where I make mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
- (void)getFBProfilePicture {
   NSString *facebookId = @"yourFacebookId";
   NSString *imageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1", facebookId];
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
     NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]];
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
     });
  });
}
```